# Operation of ` with echo when trying to awk

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, echo

How come

```
 echo `echo "foo"`
```

works but

```
 echo `awk '{ print "foo" }'`
```

doesn't?

Comment: Awk is waiting for input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `awk` program will wait for input and, for each line of input, print the word `foo`.  That is what the `awk` program `{ print "foo" }` does.

In contrast, `echo`, in the first command substitution, does not wait for input.

Would you want an `awk` program to just print something, without any input, do the output in a `BEGIN` block:

```
awk 'BEGIN { print "foo" }'
```

The `BEGIN` block is executed *before* reading the first line of input, and since there are no other blocks in the script, and no input file, it will then exit.

Also, never write code like `echo $( ... )` or `` echo ` ... ` ``, just use the code inside the command substitution instead.

Comment: All `awk`s I have also return immediately with just `awk 'BEGIN { print "foo" }'`, as does just `awk ""`, i.e. if it doesn't have any rules apart from `BEGIN`, it doesn't wait for input.